# jQuery: User must stay on page for determined time to show content

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, time

I'm having some problems with my code. As you can see below, the content of the post will only be shown if the user click on the link provided. It will unlock an action. But I need that the user must stay on the page for at least some seconds before unlock the content. If the user leave the page before this determined time, the content won't be show. Any way to do it?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var clicked = new Set;

  jQuery('.Button').click(function() {
     clicked.add(this);
        if(clicked.size>=10) jQuery('.PageLocked').hide();
        if(clicked.size>=10) jQuery('.Content').show();
     });
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this is even a consideration in your project but I feel I should mention that the more layers you add between the user and the content the more likely that you will land a penalty by Google.

Comment: No problem. I'm just testing

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could just use a [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to display the content after a certain length of time.

```
$('.Button').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.PageLocked').hide();
        $('.Content').show();
    },10000); 
});
```